# Where can I find a list of the HID SDP record values?

Tags: bluetooth, protocols, hid, bluez

I'm trying to implement an HID mouse/keyboard device with bluez.  I found a keyboard only version that worked and based my code so far on that.  Now I need to add mouse so I need to understand this record in more detail.  I have found things like the HID usage table that tells me a lot, but it isn't telling me what the "command" values are.  For example, \x05 indicates a UsagePage. The values to pass to this "command" are specified in the HID usage tables but the fact that \x05 is the right first code to use isn't.

There is a hidclient.c on the internet that comes side by side with a hidrecord.txt that has values and explains them.  That configuration unfortunately doesn't work though.  I found instead an sdp-record.xml here on SO that I can use with BlueZ to make a keyboard device.  The xml part is easy to interpret but there's a section 0x0206 that has a long number that is this HID record I'm trying to modify.  It doesn't have the necessary mouse page and I want to add those bits.

I've been scouring google and trying to interpret source code for various sdp parsers but the only one that has definitions doesn't seem to correlate accurately with what I have that is working.  I've found bits and pieces of information on like usb.org but I still can't find this basic piece of information to tie it all together.  Things I don't know are:

1. What are the codes that specify the kind of information that other values mean, such as 05 01 meaning "UsagePage GenericDesktop".  The 05 part, where would I find that information?
2. In my documented example all come in pairs, so there's the "command" and the argument.  Are they all like that?  Trying to interpret the record that works breaks down at some point and almost in a way that tells me I'm off by one or more in my indexing.  Where do I find that?
3. What all do I actually need?  If I'm reading the record that works right it would seem to contain an LED page and I don't need that if indeed it's there, unless there's some protocol dictating I do.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may want to also read the Device Class Definition for HID document (document naming is not usb.org's strong point)... https://usb.org/document-library/device-class-definition-hid-111

Answer (score 0):

This information is contained in the USB spec "Device Class Definition for HID 1.11", which can be downloaded from usb.org